# Is there a way to name Security Group Sources in the AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, console, security-groups

The title kind of says it all but what I want to know is if there is any way to label/name inbound security group sources in the AWS console. i.e.:
[image]

We have quite a bit of these rows in our security groups, so it would be awesome if there was a way to label them, but so far, I haven't found anything. Just want to know for sure.

Thanks!

Comment: No, but you *can* connect more than one security group to an instance. We create a security group for each employee with access, so an EC2 instance might have the `Webserver`, `ChrisSSH`, `BobSSH`, and `JaneSSH` SGs all assigned to it. Breaks down if you have hundreds of employees, but effective in small orgs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's kind of what I figured, but never hurts to be sure. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that helped. Another approach might be managing your security groups with a configuration management system like Ansible. It can setup and maintain security groups (along with many other AWS components), and its playbook files allow commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can connect more than one security group to an instance. We create a security group for each employee with access, so an EC2 instance might have the `Webserver`, `ChrisSSH`, `BobSSH`, and `JaneSSH` SGs all assigned to it. Breaks down if you have hundreds of employees, but effective in small orgs.